# Oracle cumulative totals by week for a given date range

Tags: oracle10g

I am using the following query to get column totals by week for a given date range...

```
SELECT to_char(week_start - 1, 'dd-MON-yy') week_end, run_qty, acc_qty, CASE WHEN run_qty <> 0 THEN ROUND(acc_qty/run_qty, 4) ELSE 0 END pct

  FROM (SELECT week_start, SUM(run_qty) run_qty, SUM(acc_qty) acc_qty

          FROM (SELECT TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(created_date), 'Monday')) week_start, NVL(SUM(run_qty), 0) run_qty, NVL(SUM(accepted_qty), 0) acc_qty

                  FROM shema.table_a 
                  WHERE (some conditions)
                    AND created_date BETWEEN :FromDate AND :ToDate 
                  GROUP BY TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(created_date), 'Monday'))
                 UNION
                 SELECT TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(to_date(zday, 'dd-mon-rrrr')), 'Monday')) week_start, 0run_qty, 0acc_qty
                   FROM (SELECT :FromDate + (level - 1) zday
                           FROM dual
                         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (:ToDate - :FromDate)))
          GROUP BY week_start
          ORDER BY week_start desc)
```

With input paramters of :FromDate = 4/31/2015 and :ToDate = 6/25/2015, this gives me the last day of each week (week defined as Monday - Sunday), the run total for each each week, the accepted total for each week, and the pct of the run total accepted for each week, in a result set that looks like so...

28-JUN-2015   0   0   0

21-JUN-2015   100   50   0.5

14-JUN-2015   50   40   0.8

07-JUN-2015   0   0   0

31-MAY-2015   0   0   0

24-MAY-2015   50   40   0.75

17-MAY-2015   80   50   0.625

10-MAY-2015   60   20   0.3333

03-MAY-2015   0   0   0

Can I use a similar approach in order to calculate a running total of the run and accepted quantities and percentage of quantity accepted over the date range provided? (to give me a result set that would look like)...

28-JUN-2015   340   200   0.5882

21-JUN-2015   340   200   0.5882

14-JUN-2015   240   150   0.625

07-JUN-2015   190   110   0.5789

31-MAY-2015   190   110   0.5789

24-MAY-2015   190   110   0.5789

17-MAY-2015   140   70   0.5

10-MAY-2015   60   20   0.3333

03-MAY-2015   0   0   0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... in case anyone runs into this thread by searching for a solution to a similar issue, I wrapped the query above inside...
SELECT week_end, run_qty, acc_qty, pct

FROM (query above)
MODEL
   DIMENSION BY(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY to_date(week_end, 'dd-MON-yy') asc) rec)

MEASURES(week_end, run_qty, acc_qty, pct)

RULES(

run_qty[rec > 1] ORDER BY rec = run_qty[cv()] + run_qty[cv() - 1],

acc_qty[rec > 1] ORDER BY rec = acc_qty[cv()] + acc_qty[cv() - 1],

pct[rec >= 0] ORDER BY rec = CASE WHEN run_qty[cv()] <> 0 THEN ROUND(acc_qty[cv()]/run_qty[cv()], 4) ELSE 0 END
          )

ORDER BY to_date(week_end, 'dd-MON-yy') desc
...and it runs quickly, giving me the expected results